# TSLint rules for checking undefined and NULL class properties

Tags: typescript, tslint

In my web applications when I define a class property which must contain some data type I always specify this data type. But application gets data asynchronously, so actually the property has undefined value and then it has real data:

```
class SomeClass {
    a: ISomeData;

    constructor() {
        getDataAsync().then((res: ISomeData) => this.a = res);
    }
}
```

I think that `a: ISomeData` is incorrect. It must be `a: ISomeData | undefined`. (It would be correct if `this.a = someData` were set synchronously in constructor)
Is there tslint rules for checking that class propertise does not have data and must have undefined type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default any type you assign can take the values undefined and null along with any type declarations you have made.

In your TypeScript config file (`tsconfig.json`) you can set the `StrictNullChecks` compiler option to true.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

From TypeScript docs on [Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> In strict null checking mode, the null and undefined values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and any (the one exception being that undefined is also assignable to void).

When you do that, a variable typed as `ISomeData` can only contain that type.

If you want undefined/null values, you'd have to type it like

```
a: ISomeData | undefined | null;
```